# TFS and resources that is changed from outside?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, visual-studio-2012, resources

**Hi,**

Its not unusual to include images in a solutions. The problem is that these images is often edited out site Visual Studio in another program and TFS will not pick up the changes. So how do you handle this? Do you need to checkout the image before changing it? What If I have forgot to do that? How do I update TSF with my setup of the solution?

**BestRegards**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different types of `workspaces` in TFS.

1. `Server Workspaces`
2. `Local Workspaces` - New in TFS 2012

**Server Workspaces**

Within `Server Workspaces` all files under source control are marked as `read only`.  This means that if you wish to edit these files outside of `Visual Studio`, the workflow would be:

1. Check out images
2. Edit images
3. Check in images

If you try to edit the files before checking them out, the external program will try to save the edited file, see that it is readonly and then either not let you save, or ask you if you wish to overwrite.  Either way **TFS does not know you have changed the file**.

**Local Workspaces**

Within `Local Workspaces`, files are not marked as read only.  You can edit them in any program you want.  `Visual Studio` will see that you have changed the file automatically and mark it as a `Pending Change`.  You can then check this file in.  The workflow would be:

1. Edit image in any program you like
2. Check in to `TFS`

This way of working is much more akin to Subversion and I think is what you are looking for.